# Problem, related to Zip4 extension, directing Standard Input Content into a zip archive, using zip, and using zipnotes to change the zipped file name

Tags: linux, zip

I have an annoying problem with `zip` and `zipnote` programs (both in 3.0 version) in my Debian stable platform.

I wish to create a zip archive storing (not compressing) data from standard input, without extra attributes/fields, and giving a name to the resulting file inside the zip file.

My first try was

```
printf "foodata"          | zip -X0 bar.zip - 
printf "@ -\n@=foofile\n" | zipnote -w bar.zip
```

where `zip` create a `bar.zip` archive, with a stored file `"-"` containing `"foodata"`, and `zipnote` rename the file from `"-"` to `"foofile"`.

First problem (solved): `zip`, as we can see from `zipdetails`

```
001E Filename              '-'
001F Extra ID #0001        0001 'ZIP64'
0021   Length              0010
0023   Uncompressed Size   0000000000000007
002B   Compressed Size     0000000000000007
```

receiving data from standard input, doesn't know the size of the resulting file so create a PKZIP 4.5 compatible `zip` archive (that can exceed 4 GB) using `Zip64` extension and adding a `Zip64` extra attribute to the file.

And the `-X` option remove extrafile attributes **but** doesn't remove the `Zip64` extra field.

This problem is easily solvable adding the `-fz-` option, as stated in `zip` man page

```
// .................................VVVV
printf "foodata"          | zip -X0 -fz- bar.zip -
```

Now `bar.zip` is a PKZIP 2 compatible file and there isn't the `Zip64` extra field.

Second problem (not solved): `zipnote` change the name of the contained file **and** add the `Zip64` field to the file.

I don't know why.

According the `zip` man page

> `zip` removes the  Zip64  extensions  if  not  needed  when  archive  entries  are  copied (see the `-U` (`--copy`) option).

So I understand that

```
zip bar.zip --out bar-corrected.zip
```

should create a new `bar-corrected.zip` archive where the file `foofile is`Zip64`free (the`foofile`is very short so the`Zip64` extension isn't needed, I presume).

Unfortunately, this doesn't works: I get the warning

```
 copying: foofile
    zip warning: Local Version Needed To Extract does not match CD: foofile
```

and the resulting file maintain the `Zip64` extension.

And seems that doesn't works explicating the filename or adding the `-fz-` option: I've tried a lot o combinations but (maybe is my fault) without success.

Questions:

(1) can I avoid (and how) that `zipnote`, changing the name of a file, add the `Zip64` fields to it?

(2) otherwise, how can I use `zip` (with `--copy`? with `-fz-`?) to create a new `zip` archive `Zip64` extension free?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: Updated to use Store rather than Deflate]

Not sure how to achieve what you want with `zip` and `zipnote`, but here is an alternative.

`echo abc | perl -MIO::Compress::Zip=zip -e ' zip "-" => "out.zip", Method => 0, Name => "member.txt" '`

```
$ unzip -lv out.zip 
Archive:  out.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       4  Stored        4   0% 2019-10-10 21:54 4788814e  member.txt
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       4                4   0%                            1 file
```

No Zip64 or extra attributes are present in the zip file.

```
$ zipdetails out.zip 

0000 LOCAL HEADER #1       04034B50
0004 Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
0005 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
0006 General Purpose Flag  0008
     [Bit  3]              1 'Streamed'
0008 Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
000A Last Mod Time         4F4AAECA 'Thu Oct 10 21:54:20 2019'
000E CRC                   00000000
0012 Compressed Length     00000000
0016 Uncompressed Length   00000000
001A Filename Length       000A
001C Extra Length          0000
001E Filename              'member.txt'
0028 PAYLOAD               abc.

002C STREAMING DATA HEADER 08074B50
0030 CRC                   4788814E
0034 Compressed Length     00000004
0038 Uncompressed Length   00000004

003C CENTRAL HEADER #1     02014B50
0040 Created Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
0041 Created OS            03 'Unix'
0042 Extract Zip Spec      14 '2.0'
0043 Extract OS            00 'MS-DOS'
0044 General Purpose Flag  0008
     [Bit  3]              1 'Streamed'
0046 Compression Method    0000 'Stored'
0048 Last Mod Time         4F4AAECA 'Thu Oct 10 21:54:20 2019'
004C CRC                   4788814E
0050 Compressed Length     00000004
0054 Uncompressed Length   00000004
0058 Filename Length       000A
005A Extra Length          0000
005C Comment Length        0000
005E Disk Start            0000
0060 Int File Attributes   0000
     [Bit 0]               0 'Binary Data'
0062 Ext File Attributes   81A40000
0066 Local Header Offset   00000000
006A Filename              'member.txt'

0074 END CENTRAL HEADER    06054B50
0078 Number of this disk   0000
007A Central Dir Disk no   0000
007C Entries in this disk  0001
007E Total Entries         0001
0080 Size of Central Dir   00000038
0084 Offset to Central Dir 0000003C
0088 Comment Length        0000
Done
```

Comment: Nice. Works. Adding "`method => 0, `" I also get that the file is stored instead of compressed. I'll wait for a `zip`/`zipnote` answer but mainly because I don't know perl so it's difficult, for me, adapt your solution to my needs. But this is a limit of mine and your answer could be useful for others with a similar problem (and for me, if nobody else can solve the problem using `zip` and `zipnote` only). Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that part. I've updated the answer to include the `Method => 0` part.

Answer (score 0):

Created a simple script that wraps the previous answer. See [streamzip](https://github.com/pmqs/IO-Compress/blob/master/bin/streamzip)

Usage is

```
 printf "foodata" | streamzip -method=store -member-name=foofile -zipfile=/tmp/bar.zip
```

This is what unzip thinks is in the zip file

```
unzip -lv /tmp/bar.zip
Archive:  /tmp/bar.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       7  Stored        7   0% 2019-10-15 20:25 1b7dd7cd  foofile
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       7                7   0%                            1 file
```